# Calculate multiple point distance matrices with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, geosphere

I know that there is a similar question about that here [Calculating geographic distances to data points with dplyr::mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807177/calculating-geographic-distances-to-data-points-with-dplyrmutate), but none of the answers really helped me to calculate it correctly.

I have something like the following data.frame:

```r
dt <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  date = c(
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02",
    "2022-05-02"
  ),
  bird_ID = c(
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E",
    "350E"
  ),
  Position_Burst_ID = c(
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2
  ),
  device_ID = c(
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L,
    202927L
  ),
  devicetype = c(
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela",
    "ornitela"
  ),
  timestamp = c(
    "2022-05-02 00:03:58",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:03:59",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:00",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01",
    "2022-05-02 00:09:01"
  ),
  sensortype = c(
    "GPS",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "GPS",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC",
    "ACC"
  ),
  GPS_ID = c(
    132933L,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    132934L,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  altitude_msl = c(
    37L,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    37L,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  latitude = c(
    64.6706237792969,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    64.6706771850586,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  longitude = c(
    40.1550903320312,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    40.1552696228027,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  ETRS89_y = c(
    4926797.58514714,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    4926806.57855044,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  ETRS89_x = c(
    5717023.89306346,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    5717028.86622297,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  ACC_ID = c(
    NA,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    2591809L,
    NA,
    2591849L,
    2591849L,
    2591849L,
    2591849L,
    2591849L,
    2591849L,
    2591849L,
    2591849L
  ),
  acc_x = c(
    NA,
    -532,
    -873,
    -562,
    -667,-728,
    -552,
    -999,
    -801,
    -555,-899,
    -788,
    -808,
    -652,-806,
    -1202,
    -707,
    -854,
    -857,-954,
    -798,
    -1044,
    -558,-1047,
    -748,
    -1114,
    -789,
    -896,-692,
    -1153,
    -637,
    -714,-920,
    -957,
    -610,
    -525,
    -1191,-593,
    -417,
    -627,
    -905,
    NA,-922,
    -691,
    -601,
    -154,-1022,
    66,
    -195,
    -587
  ),
  acc_y = c(
    NA,
    651,
    815,
    454,
    410,
    625,
    431,
    344,
    335,
    490,
    319,
    441,
    223,
    446,
    111,
    250,
    207,
    242,
    111,
    136,
    303,
    141,
    145,
    248,
    223,
    242,
    97,
    339,
    335,
    161,
    146,
    537,
    175,
    539,-29,
    799,
    -107,
    167,
    1087,
    618,
    383,
    NA,
    484,
    527,
    720,
    1199,
    537,
    911,
    1130,
    748
  ),
  acc_z = c(
    NA,
    -993,
    -732,
    -97,
    121,-529,
    -230,
    -401,
    -266,
    -881,-170,
    -321,
    -58,
    -1041,
    -117,-753,
    -821,
    -289,
    -85,
    -401,-1022,
    -97,
    78,
    -465,
    -745,-353,
    29,
    -177,
    -924,
    -241,
    112,
    -417,
    -399,
    -545,
    588,-689,
    91,
    127,
    -1356,
    -353,-187,
    NA,
    -337,
    -438,
    -65,-1163,
    -145,
    -474,
    -417,
    132
  ),
  Position.Burst.ID.length = c(
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L,
    40L
  ),
  ODBA = c(
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    25.79384765625,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375,
    31.129052734375
  ),
  latitude_m = c(
    7199133.83911133,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    7199139.78424072,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  longitude_m = c(
    -1183571.81342411,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    -1183807.30305938,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA,
    NA
  ),
  ODBA.median = c(
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875,
    20.672607421875
  ),
  latitude.sd = c(
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538,
    515.425830060538
  )
)
head(dt)
#>         date bird_ID Position_Burst_ID device_ID devicetype           timestamp
#> 1 2022-05-02    350E                 1    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:58
#> 2 2022-05-02    350E                 1    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59
#> 3 2022-05-02    350E                 1    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59
#> 4 2022-05-02    350E                 1    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59
#> 5 2022-05-02    350E                 1    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59
#> 6 2022-05-02    350E                 1    202927   ornitela 2022-05-02 00:03:59
#>   sensortype GPS_ID altitude_msl latitude longitude ETRS89_y ETRS89_x  ACC_ID
#> 1        GPS 132933           37 64.67062  40.15509  4926798  5717024      NA
#> 2        ACC     NA           NA       NA        NA       NA       NA 2591809
#> 3        ACC     NA           NA       NA        NA       NA       NA 2591809
#> 4        ACC     NA           NA       NA        NA       NA       NA 2591809
#> 5        ACC     NA           NA       NA        NA       NA       NA 2591809
#> 6        ACC     NA           NA       NA        NA       NA       NA 2591809
#>   acc_x acc_y acc_z Position.Burst.ID.length     ODBA latitude_m longitude_m
#> 1    NA    NA    NA                       40 25.79385    7199134    -1183572
#> 2  -532   651  -993                       40 25.79385         NA          NA
#> 3  -873   815  -732                       40 25.79385         NA          NA
#> 4  -562   454   -97                       40 25.79385         NA          NA
#> 5  -667   410   121                       40 25.79385         NA          NA
#> 6  -728   625  -529                       40 25.79385         NA          NA
#>   ODBA.median latitude.sd
#> 1    20.67261    515.4258
#> 2    20.67261    515.4258
#> 3    20.67261    515.4258
#> 4    20.67261    515.4258
#> 5    20.67261    515.4258
#> 6    20.67261    515.4258
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And the following tibble:

```r
locations <- tibble::tribble(
  ~bird_ID,   ~latitude.mean,         ~latitude.sd,  ~longitude.mean,        ~longitude.sd,
    "350E", 68.4523207306103, 0.000197644989661478,  52.122216437273, 0.000714616838312651,
    "351E", 70.6687025782724, 0.000217284948426624, 56.5641610797428, 0.000630191007951335,
    "373E", 69.1366802085825, 0.000136364833873454, 49.9669871427575, 0.000195497865494354,
    "375E", 67.8441058291665,   0.0236158366819919, 53.1982619611523,   0.0532271169756873,
    "379E", 70.8926167721249, 9.62097052940481e-05, 55.4907074886489, 0.000214362572617005,
    "383E",  68.454480489095, 3.83707104847611e-05, 51.5960375467936, 0.000212207883139862
  )
head(locations)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   bird_ID latitude.mean latitude.sd longitude.mean longitude.sd
#>   <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 350E             68.5   0.000198            52.1     0.000715
#> 2 351E             70.7   0.000217            56.6     0.000630
#> 3 373E             69.1   0.000136            50.0     0.000195
#> 4 375E             67.8   0.0236              53.2     0.0532  
#> 5 379E             70.9   0.0000962           55.5     0.000214
#> 6 383E             68.5   0.0000384           51.6     0.000212
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The idea is that I want to create a geographical distance matrix around the possible locations from the `locations` tibble. I want to be able to calculate the distance between the points in the `latitude` and `longitude` columns from the `dt`. I was using the following piece of code that I thought worked fine, until I run each `bird_ID` separately and the results changed.

```r
distances <- dt %>%
  group_by(bird_ID) %>%
  select(longitude, latitude, date) %>%
  mutate(Dist = distHaversine(cbind(locations$longitude.mean, locations$latitude.mean), cbind(longitude, latitude))) %>%
  drop_na()
```

[image: The results for one bird_ID]
[image: The results for all the the objects of bird_ID]

Any ideas of how should I approach this?

Comment: I get warnings (which should be errors) when I run your code. Are you ignoring them? They're key and (like I said) should be errors, since ignored they are resulting in inconsistent data results. The `distHaversine` function calcs distance in one of two ways: if only `p1` (first arg, a 2-column table/frame) is provided, then it calculates the distance between each point; if both `p1` and `p2` are provided, then they must both be either 1-row or the same length, in which case it is a 1-to-1 or 1-to-n distance calculation. You have neither.

Comment: Please think about how you want the "distance" to be calculated ... since you have six rows of `locations`, that means from each point in `dt` you should have six distances. Do you think it should be a long-table (6x the number of rows as `dt`) or a wide-table (with 6 more columns, one for each of `locations`'s rows' distance).

Comment: FYI, I don't know that the plot is really helping here, other than explain visually why you say that the results are different between the two methods of calculation. I suggest you be include the warnings you get so that it's clear that they might be or are an issue, and then you should also add what you expect the output to be from your distance-calculating pipe. Just knowing what the shape should be should help you and will definitely inform answers.

Comment: Oh, okay. First of all thank you, for the reply! 
I wanted calculate the distances between each data point from `dt` and the `location` row that matched that specific `bird_ID`. Because `dt` actually has around 30 different `bird_ID` values. So I do not want for each point to calculate its distance for all 6 locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calc distance *by `bird_ID`*, then you should likely `left_join` the `locations` onto the original data before calculating the distance.

```r
distances <- dt %>% 
  left_join(locations, by = "bird_ID") %>%   # NEW
  group_by(bird_ID) %>%
  select(bird_ID,                            # suppress an auto-add message
         longitude, latitude, date,
         longitude.mean, latitude.mean) %>%  # added so we have the data per-bird_ID
  mutate(
    Dist = geosphere::distHaversine(
      cbind(longitude.mean, latitude.mean),  # removed `location$`
      cbind(longitude, latitude))
  ) %>%
  tidyr::drop_na()
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
# # Groups:   bird_ID [1]
#   bird_ID longitude latitude date       longitude.mean latitude.mean    Dist
#   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 350E         40.2     64.7 2022-05-02           52.1          68.5 674850.
# 2 350E         40.2     64.7 2022-05-02           52.1          68.5 674840.
```

Comment: This worked remarkably, thank you!