Measuring Distance Between Lat/Longs in R using geosphere::distHaversine
I have a dataframe with the lat/long of every MLB team's ballpark and their city center between 2005 - 2019. I need to calculate the distance from the park to the city center for each observation (435). Below is the script I run, with some toy data
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)

MLB_Locations <- tibble(park_long =1:3,
                        park_lat = 1:3, 
                        city_long = 5:7,
                        city_lat = 10:12)

MLB_Locations <- MLB_Locations %>%
    mutate(distance = distHaversine(c(park_long, park_lat), c(city_long, city_lat)))

But when I run the script I get the following error message:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `distance = distHaversine(c(x, y))`.
Caused by error in `.pointsToMatrix()`:
! Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554592/geosphere-disthaversine-dplyr-error-wrong-length-for-vector-should-be-2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807177/calculating-geographic-distances-to-data-points-with-dplyrmutate

I suspect you can resolve by adding rowwise() %>% before the mutate.

You need to wrap up each pair of lat/long into a matrix with two columns. If you want something to put inside mutate, you can make a helper function like this:
helper <- function(x,y,u,v){
    distHaversine(matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2), matrix(c(u, v), ncol = 2))
}

MLB_Locations <- MLB_Locations |> 
    mutate(dist = helper(park_long, park_lat, city_long, city_lat))

